# Algorithm for detecting dead-end streets of a City

Tags: algorithm

Does anyone know or have an algorithm for detecting the dead-end streets of a specified City?
The problem is that i want to do an algorithm for detecting the dead-end streets of my City and implement it using PHP or Python. 
How can I do that ? 
Or does enyone know or have the soluction for the problem E of the 2019 ICPC World Finals. The problem can be found here: https://judge.icpc.global/problems/deadend .

Answer (score 2):

For every node, keep track of the number of edges that start or end on that node.

You have a dead end if the number of edges on a node is 1. So, after you compute the values for every node, go through the list, if you find one that has rank 1 then you remove the edge, decrease the number of the other end of the edge and recursively go check for the other end of the edge if it reached 1 edge.

This is O(E+V).